# Testdisk says Copy done! 0 ok, 0 failed on almost every file :'(

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

What causes this?

In the Boot menu I get the following warnings:

```
 Disk /dev/sdb - 12 GB / 11 GiB - CHS 1502 255 63
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
   P FAT32                    0   0  1  1502  63 33   24133632 [NO NAME]

Boot sector
check_FAT: Unusual media descriptor (0xf0!=0xf8)
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 4 (FAT) != 255 (HD)
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 16 (FAT) != 63 (HD)
OK

Backup boot sector
check_FAT: Unusual media descriptor (0xf0!=0xf8)
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 4 (FAT) != 255 (HD)
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 16 (FAT) != 63 (HD)
OK

Sectors are identical.

A valid FAT Boot sector must be present in order to access
any data; even if the partition is not bootable.
```

After choosing Rebuild BS (Bootsector) I get warnings:

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 12 GB / 11 GiB - CHS 1502 255 63
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
   P FAT32                    0   0  1  1502  63 33   24133632 [NO NAME]

FAT : 32
cluster_size 64 64
reserved     32 32
total_sect   24133632 24133632
fat32_length 2946 2946
root_cluster 2 2
free_count   uninitialised 375052
next_free    uninitialised 514
Extrapolated boot sector and current boot sector are different.
```

**After the repair boot sector is finished nothing changes:I can still copy the same amount of files as before**

How to fix this issue? (very important files)
**Maybe I should use Repair FAT Very Dangerous! Expert Only! option?**

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit more on your question.

Comment: @StBlade Dont downvote give me a chance! I was actually in middle of editing question when you downvoted D:

Comment: Will remove as soon as your question is improved.

Comment: added informations!